# AWS Glue Job stuck on running indefinitely

Tags: aws-glue

Am quite new to AWS Glue and we are building an ETL process that pull data from different sources into a redshift instance. One of them is from mixpanel.com, for that we wrote a lambda function that query raw_data in json format from mixpanel and stores it in a date format folder into s3 bucket.

Then, used AWS Glue to crawl the folder and create a table structure for the json file which was done successfully. We also defined database and connections to redshift, the job also was created successfully.

When executing the job no errors are logged, the job would run until it timeout with the following info logs

```
--conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.connect.max-wait.ms=60000 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS=hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020 --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address=ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8032 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=98 --conf spark.executor.memory=5g --conf spark.executor.cores=4 --JOB_ID j_22da3607e1f4f9ca9bb4021f83ce82bd704a98865369ca1fc0693b3bd8f687ec --JOB_RUN_ID jr_a289c915a25344c5c45742150029bdab7e48be1766821463921b9350de54d609 --scriptLocation s3://aws-glue-scripts-xxxxxxxx-us-east-1/folder_a/mixpanel-to-redshift2 --job-bookmark-option job-bookmark-disable --job-language python --TempDir s3://aws-glue-temporary-xxxxxxxx-us-east-1/folder_a --JOB_NAME mixpanel-to-redshift2
YARN_RM_DNS=ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal
Detected region us-east-1
JOB_NAME = mixpanel-to-redshift2
Specifying us-east-1 while copying script.
Completed 10.0 KiB/10.0 KiB (90.4 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
download: s3://aws-glue-scripts-xxxxxxxx-us-east-1/folder_a/mixpanel-to-redshift2 to ./script_2018-08-21-16-37-20.py
SCRIPT_URL = /tmp/g-cc03d49ea3dd3ed71e42af3c1f611dee359f977b-5918932981993359503/script_2018-08-21-16-37-20.py
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.connect.max-wait.ms=60000 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS=hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020 --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address=ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8032 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=98 --conf spark.executor.memory=5g --conf spark.executor.cores=4 --name tape --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --jars /opt/amazon/superjar/glue-assembly.jar --files /tmp/glue-default.conf,/tmp/glue-override.conf,/opt/amazon/certs/InternalAndExternalAndAWSTrustStore.jks,/opt/amazon/certs/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem,/opt/amazon/certs/redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem,/opt/amazon/certs/RDSTrustStore.jks,/tmp/image-creation-time,,/tmp/g-cc03d49ea3dd3ed71e42af3c1f611dee359f977b-5918932981993359503/script_2018-08-21-16-37-20.py --py-files /tmp/PyGlue.zip /tmp/runscript.py script_2018-08-21-16-37-20.py --JOB_NAME mixpanel-to-redshift2 --JOB_ID j_22da3607e1f4f9ca9bb4021f83ce82bd704a98865369ca1fc0693b3bd8f687ec --JOB_RUN_ID jr_a289c915a25344c5c45742150029bdab7e48be1766821463921b9350de54d609 --job-bookmark-option job-bookmark-disable --TempDir s3://aws-glue-temporary-xxxxxxxx-us-east-1/folder_a
18/08/21 16:37:23 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/08/21 16:37:23 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal/10.241.110.211:8032
18/08/21 16:37:24 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 49 NodeManagers
18/08/21 16:37:24 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (12288 MB per container)
18/08/21 16:37:24 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 5632 MB memory including 512 MB overhead
18/08/21 16:37:24 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
18/08/21 16:37:24 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
18/08/21 16:37:24 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
18/08/21 16:37:25 DEBUG Client: 
18/08/21 16:37:25 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
18/08/21 16:37:28 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-b2b371a1-29b9-4911-8b6d-d184ca2928c8/__spark_libs__224704182240168405.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/__spark_libs__224704182240168405.zip
18/08/21 16:37:31 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/amazon/superjar/glue-assembly.jar -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/glue-assembly.jar
18/08/21 16:37:36 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/glue-default.conf -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/glue-default.conf
18/08/21 16:37:36 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/glue-override.conf -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/glue-override.conf
18/08/21 16:37:36 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/amazon/certs/InternalAndExternalAndAWSTrustStore.jks -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/InternalAndExternalAndAWSTrustStore.jks
18/08/21 16:37:37 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/amazon/certs/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
18/08/21 16:37:37 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/amazon/certs/redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem
18/08/21 16:37:37 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/amazon/certs/RDSTrustStore.jks -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/RDSTrustStore.jks
18/08/21 16:37:37 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/image-creation-time -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/image-creation-time
18/08/21 16:37:37 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/g-cc03d49ea3dd3ed71e42af3c1f611dee359f977b-5918932981993359503/script_2018-08-21-16-37-20.py -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/script_2018-08-21-16-37-20.py
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/runscript.py -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/runscript.py
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/pyspark.zip
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/PyGlue.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001
/PyGlue.zip
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-b2b371a1-29b9-4911-8b6d-d184ca2928c8/__spark_conf__8624620488004095183.zip -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/__spark_conf__.zip
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: ===============================================================================
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: YARN AM launch context:
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: user class: org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: env:
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: CLASSPATH -> ./*:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*<CPS>{{PWD}}<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark_conf__<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark_libs__/*<CPS>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR -> hdfs://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: SPARK_USER -> root
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: SPARK_YARN_MODE -> true
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: PYTHONHASHSEED -> 0
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: PYTHONPATH -> {{PWD}}/pyspark.zip<CPS>{{PWD}}/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip<CPS>{{PWD}}/PyGlue.zip
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: resources:
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: image-creation-time -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/image-creation-time" } size: 11 timestamp: 1534869457929 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: py4j-0.10.4-src.zip -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip" } size: 74096 timestamp: 1534869458532 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: glue-assembly.jar -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/glue-assembly.jar" } size: 403225879 timestamp: 1534869456636 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: pyspark.zip -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/pyspark.zip" } size: 482687 timestamp: 1534869458409 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: __spark_libs__ -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/__spark_libs__224704182240168405.zip" } size: 218269777 timestamp: 1534869451273 type: ARCHIVE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem" } size: 8621 timestamp: 1534869457772 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem" } size: 26016 timestamp: 1534869457593 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: glue-default.conf -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/glue-default.conf" } size: 382 timestamp: 1534869456746 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/
08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: runscript.py -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/runscript.py" } size: 3549 timestamp: 1534869458289 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: glue-override.conf -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/glue-override.conf" } size: 276 timestamp: 1534869456853 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: InternalAndExternalAndAWSTrustStore.jks -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/InternalAndExternalAndAWSTrustStore.jks" } size: 120188 timestamp: 1534869457478 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: PyGlue.zip -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/PyGlue.zip" } size: 101883 timestamp: 1534869458663 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: __spark_conf__ -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/__spark_conf__.zip" } size: 8005 timestamp: 1534869458698 type: ARCHIVE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: RDSTrustStore.jks -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/RDSTrustStore.jks" } size: 19135 timestamp: 1534869457813 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: script_2018-08-21-16-37-20.py -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal" port: 8020 file: "/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1534869144604_0001/script_2018-08-21-16-37-20.py" } size: 10272 timestamp: 1534869458118 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: command:
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -server -Xmx5120m -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp '-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC' '-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70' '-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70' '-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled' '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p' '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=InternalAndExternalAndAWSTrustStore.jks' '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS' '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=amazon' '-DRDS_ROOT_CERT_PATH=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem' '-DREDSHIFT_ROOT_CERT_PATH=redshift-ssl-ca-cert.pem' '-DRDS_TRUSTSTORE_URL=file:RDSTrustStore.jks' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class 'org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner' --primary-py-file runscript.py --arg 'script_2018-08-21-16-37-20.py' --arg '--JOB_NAME' --arg 'mixpanel-to-redshift2' --arg '--JOB_ID' --arg 'j_22da3607e1f4f9ca9bb4021f83ce82bd704a98865369ca1fc0693b3bd8f687ec' --arg '--JOB_RUN_ID' --arg 'jr_a289c915a25344c5c45742150029bdab7e48be1766821463921b9350de54d609' --arg '--job-bookmark-option' --arg 'job-bookmark-disable' --arg '--TempDir' --arg 's3://aws-glue-temporary-xxxxxxxx-us-east-1/folder_a' --properties-file {{PWD}}/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr
18/08/21 16:37:38 DEBUG Client: ===============================================================================
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users with modify permissions: Set(root); g
roups with modify permissions: Set()
18/08/21 16:37:38 INFO Client: Submitting application application_1534869144604_0001 to ResourceManager
18/08/21 16:37:39 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1534869144604_0001
18/08/21 16:37:40 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
applicationid is application_1534869144604_0001, yarnRMDNS is ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal
Application info reporting is enabled.
----------Recording application Id and Yarn RM DNS for cancellation-----------------
10.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:49 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:49 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:50 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:50 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:51 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:51 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:52 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:52 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:53 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:53 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:54 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:54 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:55 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:55 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:56 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:56 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:57 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:57 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:58 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:58 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:37:59 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:37:59 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:38:00 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:38:00 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
18/08/21 16:38:01 INFO Client: Application report for application_1534869144604_0001 (state: RUNNING)
18/08/21 16:38:01 DEBUG Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 10.241.110.165
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1534869458945
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://ip-10-241-110-211.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1534869144604_0001/
user: root
```

We tried to increase UDP & timeout, but I doubt job would need more than 20 mints since the json file is no larger than 50MB. At this point, we are not sure how we can further debug the issue and root cause.

Your advice is highly appreciated

*Update*

After further investigation, it turned out that the JSON file is actually a JSONL format which is a valid json payload per line. AWS Glue seem to not know how to handle the file and perhaps require custom classifier